# Replace "[ to [ with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file:

```
 "tags": "['PNP']"
```

Clearly "[ is wrong, it must ot be `"tags" : ['PNP']`

So I wanna to replace with sed:

```
sed -i "1,$ s/"[/[/g" file.json
```

However it told me that it is not match

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
sed 's/"\[/\[/; s/\]"/\]/' file.json
```

The brackets [] are special characters in basic regular expressions, so you need to escape them.

On input:

```
"tags": "['PNP']"
```

This outputs:

```
"tags": ['PNP']
```